# JS animate({},{complete:}) Как передать параметры в функцию которая в complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate

Имеется простая анимация(изменение высоты блока на который кликнул),когда она завершается должна выполнится функция которая принимает блок-родитель и производит его модификацию.
Как передать блок-родитель в callback функцию описанную в complete?

```
$(".ok").animate({
  height: "300px"

}, {
  duration: 2000,
  complete: function() {
    this.changeParent(parent)
  }
});
```

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуйте так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".ok").animate({ height:"300px"}, 2000, function(){
  var parent = $(this).parent();//.parents(selector);
  changeParent(parent);
});
```